# how to respond to adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

i have a listview that i want to use with a custom list item .

the list item (list_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="start time"
    android:id="@+id/startTime"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="finish time"
    android:id="@+id/finishTime"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/payment"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the java class:

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList shifts;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, shifts);
```

My question is, when the app start running, how can i add a new list item into shifts (ArrayList), override the method notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter so the listview would "refresh", and then set the edit texts in the list item with the parameters i wish to?

I hope im clear enough..
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You don't need to override notifyDataSetChanged() at all, the adapter will do everyting, you just have to update the data of your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged on it.

Comment: ok, so how can i make a new item based on the xml item?

Comment: To customise the layout you'll want to a custom Adapter. The ArrayAdapter is there as utility to quickly create standard text-based list items. You can create your own class extending BaseAdapter and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, 
                View view, 
                int position, 
                long id)
```

Parameters
View: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

So You can find ExidText(findviewbyid) from View